# Parser Error- is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'

Tags: asp.net

I am working through this tutorial- https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview

When I get to the part to AddToCart I try to run it and get this error-

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: 'WingTipToys.AddToCart' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddToCart.aspx.cs" Inherits="WingTipToys.AddToCart" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>

Source File: /AddToCart.aspx    Line: 1
```

What should I look for?

This is the cs file-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WingtipToys.Logic;
namespace WingtipToys
{
    public partial class AddToCart : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string rawId = Request.QueryString["ProductID"];
            int productId;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rawId) && int.TryParse(rawId, out productId))
            {
                using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new
               ShoppingCartActions())
                {
                    usersShoppingCart.AddToCart(Convert.ToInt16(rawId));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Fail("ERROR : We should never get to AddToCart.aspx without a ProductId.");
            throw new Exception("ERROR : It is illegal to load AddToCart.aspx without setting a ProductId.");
            }
            Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the class definition for `AddToCart`?

Comment: I added the cs file. Is that what you were looking for? I am just starting out by working through this tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error as well. Check your AddToCart.aspx and check the Inherits="WingTipToys.AddToCart".

This should actually be "WingtipToys.AddToCart". I made that change and it worked for me.